# Mobile device reconnecting to the same TCP server behind Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am developing an app which does not use HTTP nor HTTPS but custom binary protocol on TCP. For example, a game program.

Given that there are a smartphone A, a load balancer L(e.g. [AWS ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing%E2%80%8E)) and TCP socket server machines X and Y.

[image]

A connects to X or Y by connecting to L. As the protocol is not HTTP, L forwards the connection to X or Y in random. We assume A is connected to X.
Now, A changes the network from Wifi to Cellular. IP address of A is changed. A connects to X or Y again. L forwards the connection to X or Y in random, again. There is no guarantee that A always connects to X.

However, I want to make A always connect to the same server X even if the IP address of A is changed. Can I do this? For example, A sends a proxy or XFF information to server in the TCP connection stream, before sending other data(A masquerade way)? If I can do, please let me know the guideline or the document URL.

I just want to make A reconnect to the same server after IP change. Specifying or strict binding to X or Y is not the goal.

Meanwhile, I checked out this pages, but I cannot find the answer yet.

- https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-proxy-protocol/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html

Comment: if its going through a load balancer you have to leave it to do its job.

Comment: The only way something like this is able to be performed is through session stickiness, have a look at this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html but if you plan to change IP address you won't be able to get the same effect that stickiness provides.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. Reveal public endpoint for each TCP server. ([Link](https://serverfault.com/questions/956590/setting-a-public-endpoint-for-each-server-which-is-behind-a-load-balancer))
2. On the first connection, TCP server give its public endpoint data to the client.
3. On the reconnection, client connects to TCP server with the endpoint being given in the previous phase, not the load balancer endpoint.